# use of passive past participle

Tags: грамматика

did i use осознанный correctly here? I want a correct example to put in anki. I intended the sentence to be:

> The problem that is known by you should be finished by you.
>
> Проблема, осознанная тобой тебе нужно закончить.

Comment: The Russian sentence isn't correct. The minimal correction to make it sound right at least grammatically would be "Проблема, осознанная [обнаруженная?] тобой, должна быть закончена [решена?] тобой." (I am not sure about your English sentence, as I am not a native English speaker, but it doesn't look quite correct to me, either. Do you mean something like "if it was you who found this problem, it should be you who solve it"? Or "if you know how to solve it, then you should solve it yourself [e.g. don't ask for help - you know enough to deal with it already]"?)

Comment: hahah, the sentence was only meant to show me how the case is used in russian, but thank you

Comment: UI would say that "осознанная" is more about understanding, rationalizing, "grokking", than about mere "knowing" about the problem existence. So I think the translation is a bit off here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better use ruscorpora.ru for such purposes.

Besides the well-known

> Свобода – это **осознанная необходимость**.

there are a lot of other examples

> Первая **осознанная улыбка** сына досталась отцу.
>   Это первая **осознанная попытка** найти выход их тупика. Это не размышления, а **осознанная позиция**.

You can also use dictionaries.

> Vivien had made a conscious effort to be friendly.
>   Вивьен сделала **осознанную попытку** проявить дружелюбие.  ☰
>
> She made a conscious decision to leave the painting unfinished.
>   Она приняла **осознанное решение** оставить картину незаконченной.  ☰
>
> I read about the various options so that I could make an informed choice.
>   Я читал о различных вариантах, поэтому мог сделать **осознанный выбор**.  ☰
>
> He took a calculated risk and got in on the ground floor of the new enterprise.
>   Он пошёл на **осознанный риск** и пробрался на первый этаж нового предприятия.  ☰
>
> Good information is essential if people are to make informed choices about services.
>   Чтобы люди могли сделать **осознанный выбор** в отношении услуг, необходима достоверная информация.  ☰

Your example isn't quite correct

> Проблему,осознанную тобой, необходимо решить

Comment: Else 'проблема, осознанная  тобой, должна быть решена'

Answer (score 3):

Typically, it's not natural to use that participle with *dependent words*. Its usage is closer to that of an *adjective*, as the examples in another answer clearly show. So just a grammatical correction wouldn't give a good Russian sentence. However, it is possible to imagine a rare situation (in a dialogue) where it might sound natural enough, considering emphasis on pronouns:

> (- Проблему какую-то, говоришь, осознал!?)
>
> Осознанную **тобой** проблему **тебе же** и решать!
>
> (It's up to you to solve the problem you feel!)